# Arduino analogWrite not reading correct voltage

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm experiencing a problem with my analogRead. It is recording 3.74 volts from my 100 ohm resistor. However my multimeter is correctly reading 1.19 volts. I have attached my set up and Arduino IDE.[breadboard set up, green wire to analog in A3, yellow wire to 5V pin, orange wire to GND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p96Ey.jpg)

Comment: analogRead doesn't return volts

Comment: Do you have your multimeter between A3 ad GND? If yes, the calculation from analogRead result to your output is wrong, If no, then you measure something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Juraj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3518383/juraj) said, analogRead does not return volts, instead it returns a number that must be converted to volts using a formula. Assuming that the conversion you use in your code is ok, both readings are ok as well. Look at the attached picture.
[image: schematic for the circuit]

The arduino es measuring the voltage across one point of R2 and ground, if you apply the formula for voltage divider, it is V1=( (R2+R3)/(R1+R2+R3) ) * 5V = (330/430)*5 = 3.8 volts. If your multi-meter is measuring 1.1volts, I think you are measuring the voltage between the two points of R2. If you calculate the current of the circuit it is almost 11.6 mA, and multiply by the resistor you are measuring, then you have V2 = (R2) * 11.6 mA = (100) * (0.0116) = 1.16 volts.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I swapped the ground wire (orange) and  "live" wire (yellow). I am now getting 1.21 volts :-)